# calculate the difference between pandas rows in pairs

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of orders as below, where the column 'Value' represents cash in/out and the 'Date' column reflects when the transaction occurred.

Each transaction is grouped, so that the 'QTY' out, is always succeeded by the 'QTY' 'in', reflected by the sign in the 'QTY' column:

```
    Date       Qty  Price       Value       
0   2014-11-18  58  495.775716  -2875499    
1   2014-11-24 -58  484.280147  2808824    
2   2014-11-26  63  474.138699  -2987073  
3   2014-12-31 -63  507.931247  3199966    
4   2015-01-05  59  495.923771  -2925950    
5   2015-02-05 -59  456.224370  2691723
```

How can I create two columns, 'n_days' and 'price_diff' that is the difference in days between the two dates of each transaction and the 'Value'?

I have tried:

```
df['price_diff'] = df['Value'].rolling(2).apply(lambda x: x[0] + x[1])
```

but receiving a key error for the first observation (0).

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use `sum`:

```
df['price_diff'] = df['Value'].rolling(2).sum()
```

Although from the name, it looks like

```
df['price_diff'] = df['Price'].diff()
```

And, for the two columns:

```
df[['Date_diff','Price_diff']] = df[['Date','Price']].diff()
```

Output:

```
        Date  Qty       Price    Value Date_diff  Price_diff
0 2014-11-18   58  495.775716 -2875499       NaT         NaN
1 2014-11-24  -58  484.280147  2808824    6 days  -11.495569
2 2014-11-26   63  474.138699 -2987073    2 days  -10.141448
3 2014-12-31  -63  507.931247  3199966   35 days   33.792548
4 2015-01-05   59  495.923771 -2925950    5 days  -12.007476
5 2015-02-05  -59  456.224370  2691723   31 days  -39.699401
```

---

**Updated** Per comment, you can try:

```
df['Val_sum'] = df['Value'].rolling(2).sum()[1::2]
```

Output:

```
        Date  Qty       Price    Value   Val_sum
0 2014-11-18   58  495.775716 -2875499       NaN
1 2014-11-24  -58  484.280147  2808824  -66675.0
2 2014-11-26   63  474.138699 -2987073       NaN
3 2014-12-31  -63  507.931247  3199966  212893.0
4 2015-01-05   59  495.923771 -2925950       NaN
5 2015-02-05  -59  456.224370  2691723 -234227.0
```

Comment: Many thanks for this, I actually need the sum of the value, rather than the price, as the value is the 'QTY' * 'Price', so at row 1, it should be the sum of -2875499 + 2808824 = -66,675?

Comment: That's what the first piece of code does.

Comment: Agreed, however I only need the difference for each pair of values in a transaction i.e. one value for each? For example, I only need the price_diff when the sign of QTY is negative, as this reflects the close of the order?

Comment: @cmp That's easy, just mask the even rows. See updated answer.

Comment: why didn't I think of that *facepalm*. Thank you very much for your help!